# jquery-ui menu as context menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-contextmenu

How do I use http://jqueryui.com/menu/ as a context menu on right mouse click. Is there a plugin or something?

jquery-1.9.0 jquery-ui-1.10.0

Comment: you can try this one: http://addyosmani.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html

Comment: Have a look at `$(el).on("contextmenu", function() {})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution quickly hacked together from the jquery ui sample page:
[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ejahak/1/edit)

Comment: Thx it works but now I have the problem with hide() on left mouse click $(document).click(function (e) {$("#menu").hide();}); After hidding and clicking again menu possision is bad. maybe you know how to fix it?

Comment: Found the fix: $(document).click(function (e) {
   $("#menu").hide();
   $("#menu").css("top", "");
   $("#menu").css("left", "");
  });

Answer (score 6):

Here I started a plugin for this purpose: [jquery-ui-contextmenu](https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu)
(supports delegation and creating menu definitions from JS objects).

Comment: FYI I added ".css('z-index','9999')" in the create function. This makes the plugin perfect for use with jquery fullcalendar :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin I wrote called [Audero Context Menu](https://github.com/AurelioDeRosa/Audero-Context-Menu).